# how to create a theme with QT

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt, pyqt4

im looking for a way to make my pyqt interface look nicer by adding a theme to it. 
im new to Qt and i still have no idea how to add a custom theme for widgets.. so how is that possible ?  
and is it possible through qt designer ?  
sorry for my bad english , its my third language. i hope the idea is clear enough .
 please let me know if something was unclear .. 
 thanks in advace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most easily implemented method is via Qt's [style sheets](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet.html) that are quite similar to CSS. Take a look at the [style reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/style-reference.html) if you need anything more complicated. Qt Designer does give you access to the [styleSheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#styleSheet-prop) property, although I'd recommend using a separate file for it if you're doing anything non-trivial.